# SQL Method to report next period value for this period

Tags: sql, db2-400

This may already be answered, but I can't figure out the correct search terms for what I need.  We store values by Year / Period for the Beginning of Month (BOM).   The BOM for one month is the same value as End of Month (EOM) for the previous month.   I need a way to report this as such.
So 2018-02 BOM = 2018-01 EOM.

I thought I might be able to use something simple, but it does not account for the month/year wrap at 12 months as those fields are numerical.

```
select yr as YEAR, (pd-1) as PERIOD, sum(BOM) as EOM
from Table1
where type = '3'
group by yr, pd
order by yr desc, pd desc
```

This works for the middle months, but not for January, which becomes 2018-0 instead of 2017-12.

```
Example Data
Yr     Pd     Type        BOM
18     02       3         100
18     02       3         100
18     02       2         200
18     02       2         100
18     01       3         100
18     01       3         100
18     01       2         200
18     01       2         100
18     01       3         100
18     01       2         300
17     12       3         100
17     12       3         200
17     12       2         300
17     12       3         200
17     12       2         100
17     11       3         300
17     11       2         400
17     11       3         400
17     11       2         100
```

So the results I am looking for would be:

```
Yr      Pd      EOM
18      01      200
17      12      300
17      11      500
17      10      700
```

I'm working in System iNavigator currently, but hoping to move this into an externally connected Excel query at some point.

Comment: Please share your sample data & expected output data to make it more clear.

Comment: `CASE WHEN pd-1 = 0 THEN 12 ELSE pd-1 END AS PERIOD` may get you in the ballpark. You've stored date values as integers and now you are dealing with the consequences of that decision.

Comment: Updated with example / results as best I could.    Also - I did not store the date values that way, I am querying a table someone else created / maintained.  And yes - it's teaching me the value of DATES early on in my SQL career.  :D

Comment: I'm currently working in System iNavigator - so it's an IBM AS400 database.  I am hoping to move it into an externally connected Excel query at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DB2 database should be able to use [CASE WHEN](https://community.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7601.case-expressions)

Which can be used to calculate the year and the month, depending on the month.

**For example:**

```
select
 CASE WHEN pd = 1 THEN yr - 1 ELSE yr END as Yr, 
 CASE WHEN pd = 1 THEN 12 ELSE pd - 1 END as Pd, 
 SUM(BOM) as EOM
from Table1
where type = '3'
group by yr, pd
order by yr desc, pd desc
```